# Can't Execute Python Script

Tags: python, terminal, execution

I'm learning Python via 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python' and I'm stuck on being able to execute my programs. I have the directory to my Python install added to my system environment variables (see below). When I run 'py' or 'python' from the terminal, it does bring up the Python window. However, when I try to run a specific program (for example, named pw.py) by typing 'py pw.py' or 'python pw.py' nothing happens. I have a shebang line in my program (#! python3). It looks like the window briefly tries to come up, but then nothing. Any ideas?

Here is the program:

```
#! python3
PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6','blog':'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v0lif1MLZF3sdt','luggage': '12345'}
import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) <2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py[account] -  copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]  #first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print ('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print ('There is no account named ' + account)
```

Path added

[image]

[Using Admin Command Prompt (some of these are typos - hit enter too fast)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL6PZ.jpg)

Comment: what is the contents of your .py file? Does it print or prompt something so that you can see the output on the terminal?

Comment: Here is the program - it is supposed to copy the 'password' but it doesn't copy it. Nothing prints or pops up after I enter it into the terminal.

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: copy password from where?

Comment: Code added above

Comment: In the installation folder find the python.exe file and add it to your path.

Comment: If you're typing `python pw.py` then sys.argv will be the list ['pw.py'].  I think you're getting an error message, but the window is disappearing before you can see it.  You need to type `python pw.py <account name>'.  Also, you don't need the shebang.

Comment: I added the .exe file to my system environment path. I also tried running 'python pw.py <email> and still nothing. I also just tried deleting the shebang line, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is not with your "PATH". It is the way you execute the file.

Ideally, it should be,

> python [python-file-name].py [command-line-arguments]

In my case it was,

> python test.py email

In your case,

> python [your_file_name.py] [email|blog|luggage]

This works like charm for me in both command line and IDE in both the usecases

i.e with and without command line args. Just check if you are giving it the right way

[image: Screen shot of my execution]

### Additional information :

From the screen shot, I see that you are using windows 10 (Correct me if am wrong). In windows 10, you have 2 command prompts.

1. One is for the regular users
2. The other one is in administrator mode.

**python will not launch on regular command prompts.**

I think you are using the regular mode command prompt. Please use the command prompt with admin access.

Check [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) link to see how to open cmd prompt as an admin. I think you can also open by right clicking on the windows icon.

If you still wanna use the regular cmd prompt you may also try python -i (interactive mode)

Comment: Umm, sitting on Windows 10 and python will totally launch on regular command prompts (as in cmd; less happy running interactively under gitbash but that's a separate issue solved by prefacing command with winpty).  Your admin required comment is wrong and a security not-best practice.  If you actually need an admin command prompt to run python, you probably should raise that as a separate question, possibly on a related SO site (after first probably trying to uninstall python and reinstall as a regular user)

Comment: @Foon I had the same problem in my windows 10 a couple of months back. I presumed justlearning has the same problem and this admin thing fixed the issue. What surprises me is that, the same program which justlearning has mentioned works fine in my environment

Comment: @Foon let me double check the admin cmd prompt part and edit my answer if required

Comment: Ok, I have tried various commands in the admin access command prompt window, and still no luck. I'll add a screenshot above. The first error is making me wonder - do my Python files have to be saved anywhere specific? I just have them in a folder on my C: drive. My file name is pw.py

Comment: @justlearning I just checked your screen shot. May I know where is your file pw.py located?  Right now you are running it from the system32 folder of windows.Pls try navigating to the folder wherever your file is located and then type python pw.py email. example if it is in C:/test, navigate to the test folder in C drive and type the aforementioned command

Comment: @DineshKumar I have my pw.py file located in C:\Python Scripts. how do I run it from a different folder? When I open the command prompt window, even if I have my Python Scripts folder open, it still runs it from system32.

Comment: Figured it out - finally! I had to shift+right click in my Python Scripts folder and open the command window from there. Thanks all for helping me getting this to work!

Answer (score 0):

This struck me as weird when I came across this example in the same book and I thought it was a one off but he keeps using them. The shebang line is wrong in the book. It should be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Or whatever your full path is to python3.

A shebang line must be #! and then whitespace and then a forward slash. No pathname expansion is done to find the interpreter (env or python3) so you must specify the full path. The space and interpreter name without its full path just won't work. In Appendix B at the end of the book, there is a short section that explains how to setup the shebang line properly, but yet this is at the end of the book. He does mention it in the first example, but being a beginner book, I'm sure this threw more than a few people off.

Curiously in Appendix B he states:

> On Windows, the shebang line is #! python3.

This reflects the usage in the book, but as far as I know, shebang lines don't have any effect in Windows. Someone correct me if I'm wrong. I think the book should have used #!/usr/bin/env python3 in it's examples to save confusion.

Answer (score 0):

My issue likes yours, but this is what i tried, and it worked.

First, in CMD, from any path, you can launch Python by typing python

like:

```
c:\>python
```

This means your windows path is correct.

Second, try to change your folder directory to the python code folder,  in my case, it is c:\my documents\PythonCode. The command is:

```
cd "My Documents"\PythonCode
```

After this cmd, it should look like

```
C:\My Documents\PythonCode>
```

Last, type

```
python test.py
```

This should execute your py script.

So, in your case, you can try this:

```
c: 
cd c:\"Python Scripts"
python pw.py email
```

first line sets your directory to c drive
second line sets your directory to Python Scripts folder
third line execute your pw.py script.